# How to format input text number with grouping correctly in Angular 5 app?

Tags: javascript, angular, forms

I have the following object definition:

```
export class Company {
  id : number;
  my_number: number;
```

I have the following input from the template:

```
<input type="text" #myNumber="ngModel" name="my_number" [(ngModel)]="company.my_number" [groupingFormat]="company.my_number" id="aum_usd">
```

The groupingFormat directive is working fine and his job is to apply grouping
when the number getting longer. Example: 1000 -> 1,000

The problem is that 1,000 is string and when I click save the database show null.

Do I actually need to remove the "," before saving (hard work) or is there something I am missing ?

Comment: you'll need to remove the commas if your server side code doesn't understand the formatted string.. You can do that before or after you send it to the server. As a side note, no matter how much you want the value of that input element to be a number, it isn't ...it is a string. It sounds as if, by adding commas, you've made it more difficult for your server side to parse that string received (via AJAX presumably). But, your server is parsing strings, HTTP only understands text (character) data type with only a few exceptions - numbers are not one of them.

Comment: company.my_number is type number so I'll try to add new string property to the component and use it instead company.my_number and parse to number before saving.

Comment: Please keep in mind the "type number" and "type string" are TypeScript facades that only provide static analysis. They have no run-time value whatsoever - especially when sending data to a server via AJAX. JavaScript together with the DOM APIs are the underlying tech that are controlling what happens at run time.

Comment: Yes, but I'll have to keep object in type number cause the server side is java Long.

Comment: You clearly didn't read my comment. The browser sends TEXT via HTTP to the server - everything gets transported as a string. Java (Spring or whatever) is typecasting a STRING it receives from the HTTP server regardless of what you declare in your TypeScript code. Other than being smart about how this all works, none of that is relevant to your question.